# Mails sent by PHPMailer becomes spam

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, spam

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            try {
                //Server settings
                $mail->AddReplyTo('from@from.com','Post');
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                 
                $mail->isSMTP();                                      
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';  
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                $mail->Username = 'from@from.com';                 
                $mail->Password = 'loginPassword';                           
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->isHTML(true);

                $mail->setFrom('from@from.com,'Name');
                $mail->addAddress('to@to.com', 'Name');

                //Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                $mail->Subject = $mailSub;
                $mail->Body    = $mailMsg;
                $mail->AltBody = $mailMsgAlt;

                $mail->send();
                echo "Mail sent!;
            }catch (Exception $e){
                echo "Mail not sent! Try again.";
            }
```

This is how my code looks like, ofc the $mailSub, $mailMsg, $mailMsgAlt variables are defined!
Can you help me please, I can't find why the mails always go to the spam folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail is put into spam folder by the recipient mail handler and it doesn't depend on the sender ( but actually it does and we'll look at it ).

A mail is marked as spam depending on the previous feedback from other mass users or same user. But internally, if the mail is not sent through a trusted mail redirector, with proper certification and encryption, it will be marked as spam.

A trusted mail redirector is who authenticates the email id of the sender, as the receiver can't do it. In this case, we can use whatever `from` address we want, but the mail redirector won't check whether we actually own that email id. So it is not a trusted mail redirector.

For example, if you are using Gmail API for sending an email, you will have a unique API key to prove that you are the owner of the `from` address you use. If the API key is wrong, you will get an error and the email won't be sent. That way, spam emails are prevented.

Comment: Okey, You were right, I just switched the sender all the time and still nothing until I changed the recipient to another from my mail accounts and it is working fine.